# Increase size of the slider thumb in react-native on android

Tags: slider, react-native

Is there a way to make slider's button/thumb (that green circle) bigger, to set height and width. In iOS, it looks nice, but on Android is so small.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply this on element style:

```
transform: [{ scaleX: 1.5 }, { scaleY: 1.5 }]
```

Comment: You'll need to do some tricker to get the width right. I did this:
`width: Demensions.get('width') / 1.5,
alignSelf: 'center'`

Comment: Is there any way to increase the line height ??

Comment: When using this, the resolution is quite poor, which makes sense since it is scaling up the existing pixels without re-rendering it in a higher resolution. Any workaround for that?

Answer (score 2):

As of now, there is no props that you can supply to the slider component to make the thumb bigger. Of-course you can customise the thumb for iOS as per react-native documentation but not for android.

There is library that you can make use of here -> [react-native-slider](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider)

This is a pure javascript library that make use of Animated and PanResponder.

Comment: NOTE: `react-native-slider` hasn't been updated for 1+ years and doesn't look to be actively maintained.

Comment: That's true, well this question is 2 years old, isn't it? At that time, we could take help by understanding what's going on in react-native-slider's source code

Comment: Absolutely. Not a knock against your answer. Just want to let other people know that are seeing this today, like me. :)